# How to add an item in the middle of list in perl

Tags: perl

How to add an item in the middle of the list in Perl latest version.If there is any method, please help me out
ex:

```
@array=qw(apple mango waterlemon pineapple lemon);
print("@array\n");
```

This is the code and now I need to append an item "sapota" in the list with index[3]. How can I add this

Comment: In Perl, there are array variables and list values.  A value is never an array value.  A variable is never a list variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[splice](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) is what you need.

```
splice @array, 3, 0, 'sapota';
```